# How to reload action which calls partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've added Circliful stats circles to my dashboard, but now having problem with data refresh on them. The ajax refresh the data but not the circles.

Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult GetDailyOutput(string dateFrom, string dateTo, string line = "All")
    {
        Graph g = repository.Graphs.Where(p => p.GraphID == 2).FirstOrDefault();
        DataTable dt = repository.GetGraphData(g.StoredProc + " '" + line + "', '" + dateFrom + "', '" + dateTo + "'");
        return PartialView(dt);
    }
```

View:

```
<div id="dvDailyOutput" class="col-md-12">
    @Html.Action("GetDailyOutput", "Graph")
</div>
```

PartialView:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
```

@using System.Data

```
foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
{
            <div class="product-box col-md-3">
                @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
        {
            if (col.ColumnName == "Product")
            {
                <div class="product-box-name col-md-2 vertical">@row[col.ColumnName]</div>
            }
            else if (col.ColumnName == "DemYield" || col.ColumnName == "FFSYield")
        {
            <div class="">
                <div class="yieldCircle" data-dimension="100" data-text="@row[col.ColumnName]%"
                     data-width="5" data-fontsize="20" data-percent="@row[col.ColumnName]" data-fgcolor="#61a9dc" data-bgcolor="#eee"></div>

            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="col-md-2">@row[col.ColumnName]</div>

        }
    }
            </div>
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
var selectedLine = "All";
var dateFrom = null;
var dateTo = null;


function onCriteriaChange() {
$.post('@Url.Action("GetDailyOutput", "Graph")', { line: selectedLine, dateFrom: dateFrom, dateTo: dateTo }, function (data) {
        $("#dvDailyOutput").html(data);
    });
```

There are some other scripts which updates the line and dates variables, but I have omit them for clarity.

Do you know how can I redraw the circles or if not possible how can I reload partial view?

Thanks

Comment: Need clarification. where is  function onCriteriaChange() getting called? Is there an event handler which calls this function?

Comment: there is a button which change variable "selectedLine" and calls onCriteriaChange.

Comment: First thing, since you are getting the data you should use $.get. So if your request parameters don't change the browser won't fetch the data again. In order to find why partial view is not refreshed, check if your controller method is getting hit. Put a debugger in success handler check what data is being returned.

Comment: ok, I probably didn't explain it properly, the partialView updates correctly, only the Circliful stats circles don't (the class id "yieldCircle").  On my partial view I have Output values and Yield values. Output values are updating correctly, but the yield values which are Circliful circles are not. The circles disappears after update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved this script intro the Partial view and it works straight away.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.yieldCircle').circliful();
});
</script>
```